# Ways to speed up user implemented RK4

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

So, I've implemented RK4, and I'm wondering what I can do to make it more efficient? What I've got so far is below. I wish to still record all steps. I think `AppendTo` is doing the most damage to the time, is there a faster alternative?

```
rk4[f_, variables_, valtinit_, tinit_, tfinal_, nsteps_] := 
  Module[{table, xlist, ylist, step, k1, k2, k3, k4}, 
   xlist = tinit;
   step = N[(tfinal - tinit)/(nsteps)];
   ylist = valtinit;
   table = {{xlist, ylist}};
   Table[
    k1 = step* f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, ylist}]; (* 
    Equivalent to step* f/.Thread[Rule[variables,ylist]]*)
    k2 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k1/2 + ylist}];
    k3 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k2/2 + ylist}];
    k4 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k3 + ylist}];
    ylist += 1/6 (k1 + 2 (k2 + k3) + k4);
    xlist += step;
    AppendTo[table, {xlist, ylist}];
    {xlist, ylist}, nsteps];
   table
   ];
```

Example Input:

```
funclist = {-x + y, x - y};
initials = {1, 2};
variables = {x, y};
init = 0;
final = 200;
nstep = 20000;
approx = rk4[funclist, variables, initials, init, final, nstep]//AbsoluteTiming;
```

> {3.59932,{...}}

I'd love some suggestions!

Comment: `AppendTo` is quadratic time complexity. Might be better to preallocate and set by index. Also it'll be much faster to not use `Rule` and instead code stuff up a little bit more explicitly. As a general rule, too, use vectorized operators. Those can be *very* fast. And if everything can be totally functional over "packed arrays" (look them up here) it'll be very quick too.

Comment: I'll work on implementing it more explicity, this is what came to find first though. It'll require some changes to the inputs, I'll have to ponder this. And preallocating the list is a quick change that won't be an issue to do, I can't believe I forgot that's faster :(. Thanks though!

Comment: Shinaoloard, using `Join[
 {{xlist, ylist}},
 Table[
  k1 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, ylist}];
  k2 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k1/2 + ylist}];
  k3 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k2/2 + ylist}];
  k4 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k3 + ylist}];
  ylist += 1/6 (k1 + 2 (k2 + k3) + k4);
  xlist += step;
  {xlist, ylist},
  nsteps
  ]
 ]` as return value is already a first step. There is no point in appending if you use a `Table` anyways.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher do you think it would be faster to Pre-allocate a list of length nsteps, and append the values, or to join the values using table? I can obviously change `Table` to `Do` to remove the time it takes to make the table list, going by b3m2a1's method, or I could use `Join` as you have suggested. I'm thinking your method may be faster, though. I've already removed the `MapThread` part, I am testing the speed increase granted by that at the moment. Just curious which path you think will be faster.

Comment: I am currently testing the speed difference between the one in the post and `rk4t2[f_, valtinit_, tinit_, tfinal_, nsteps_] := 
  Module[{test, table, xlist, ylist, step, k1, k2, k3, k4}, 
   xlist = tinit;
   step = N[(tfinal - tinit)/(nsteps)];
   ylist = valtinit;
   table = {{xlist, ylist}};
   test = Table[
     k1 = step* f[ylist] ;
     k2 = step*f[k1/2 + ylist];
     k3 = step*f[k2/2 + ylist];
     k4 = step*f[k3 + ylist];
     ylist += 1/6 (k1 + 2 (k2 + k3) + k4);
     xlist += step;
     {xlist, ylist}, nsteps];
   Join[table, test]
   
   ];`

Comment: Changing those two things cut the timing down form 3.5 to 0.7, apparently o.o

Comment: Why not just get `NDSolve[]` to use fourth-order Runge-Kutta to begin with?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive is was an exercise that I went on to see if I could do it, because when I had a class and had to do it in MATLAB, I had it working (with an error for vectored equations), and wanted to see if I could easily/quickly do it in Mathematica. My next step will be implementing Adaptive RK4/5. I know for all practical purposes, `NDSolve` will be miles ahead of anything  I can do .

Comment: What I meant was that you can in fact force `NDSolve[]` to use fourth-order Runge-Kutta, so that it should give the same results as your program. There are instructions for doing so in the docs.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive I know it can, I just wanted to make sure I could actually code it myself, instead of just using options to get Mathematica to do it for me (:. Thanks for trying to help though!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just to give you an impression how fast things may get when you use the right tools.

For given stepsize `τ` and given vector field `F`, this creates a `CompiledFunction` `cStep`  that computes a single Runge-Kutta step

```
F = X \[Function] {-Indexed[X, 2], Indexed[X, 1]};

τ = 0.01;
Block[{YY, Y, k1, k2, k3, k4},
  
  YY = Table[Compile`GetElement[Y, i], {i, 1, 2}];
  k1 = τ F[YY];
  k2 = τ F[0.5 k1 + YY];
  k3 = τ F[0.5 k2 + YY];
  k4 = τ F[k3 + YY];
  
  cStep = With[{code = YY + (k1 + 2. (k2 + k3) + k4)/6. },
    Compile[{{Y, _Real, 1}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
  ];
```

Now we can apply it 20 million times with `NestList` and it stills takes only about 2 seconds.

```
nsteps = 20000000;
xlist = Range[0., τ nsteps, τ];
Ylist = NestList[cStep, {1., 0.}, nsteps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 2.08678

## Edit

This can be sped up even more my avoiding `NestList` (the loop behind it can also be compiled which saves several calls to libraries) and by utilizing that the dimension of the ODE is known at compile time. For low dimensional systems, it may be also beneficial to avoid tensor operations altogether and to perform computations in scalar registers as done below.

```
τ = 0.01;
cFlow = Block[{YY, Y, k1, k2, k3, k4, τ, Ylist, j},
   YY = Table[Compile`GetElement[Ylist, j, i], {i, 1, 2}];
   k1 = τ F[YY];
   k2 = τ F[0.5 k1 + YY];
   k3 = τ F[0.5 k2 + YY];
   k4 = τ F[k3 + YY];
   With[{
     code1 = (YY + (k1 + 2. (k2 + k3) + k4)/6)[[1]],
     code2 = (YY + (k1 + 2. (k2 + k3) + k4)/6)[[2]]
     },
    Compile[{{Y0, _Real, 1}, {τ, _Real}, {n, _Integer}},
     Block[{Ylist},
      Ylist = Table[0., {n + 1}, {Length[Y0]}];
      Ylist[[1]] = Y0;
      Do[
       Ylist[[j + 1, 1]] = code1;
       Ylist[[j + 1, 2]] = code2;
       ,
       {j, 1, n}];
      Ylist
      ],
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
   ];
Ylist2 = cFlow[{1., 0.}, τ, nsteps]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.06549

Don't be too upset by parts of the code being highlighted in red; this is on  purpose.

Comment: Damn, you definitely know how to use Mathematica A LOT more efficiently than I do. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I'll have to play around with `Compile`, it definitely seems like a massive speed up if used correctly.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I like to show people when they complain about the slowness of Mathematica. Of course with some cleverness in vectorized operations `Compile` could probably be avoided altogether if one so desired.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yeah, right. However, with ODE systems of this small dimension (dim = 2) I am not sure how to utilize vectorization since the ODE has to be solved in serial and because the vector field `F` may be very nonlinear.

Comment: I don't feel it's slow, if you use it right. I can make C++ do this very slowly, or Matlab too. Using the wrong tools will make it slower in any programming language. I'll be honest though, I don't 100% understand what the function in the post is doing in certain steps, but I feel as though I have an idea, at least.

Comment: Might be of interest: JM's blog article https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2019/04/03/the-runge-kutta-gill-method/

Comment: Hey @anderstood, thank you for the link!